# Triage review: wasting flags because question status is not properly updated

Tags: discussion, review-queues, closed-questions, triage

I have recently started triage and I have quite often (about 10 times in 2 days) found questions in the review queue that have actually been closed for days or weeks but are shown to me as active until I make a decision. This mainly concerns posts related to spam or totally offtopic questions that are closed quite quickly with the result that I waste flags to request the closure of already closed posts. You could certainly tell me that I only need to open the question page via the appropriate link to check the current status of the post, but I sincerely find this step an avoidable element (if the page updates after my action, why can't it do so before?) and in contrast with the speed of interaction offered by the rest of the triage interface.
Have you encountered the same problem? Is it a problem with the interface?

### A few examples

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: You aren't wasting flags. These are audits. Every action you take on an audit is a "dummy" action; it's only checking to see if you are paying attention and making the correct decision on what should be obvious cases.

Comment: @CodyGray I honestly wasn't aware of audit testing. This is the reason why I lost the keyword and consequently the duplicate questions. I was never shown the message contained in the answer linked in another comment "congratulations, it was just a test": if I had been shown I would have obviously avoided this duplicate

Comment: "Review audit passed n ago" should have been a good clue. ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray ok, my bad

Comment: No problem. We're happy to help explain. You did the right thing by asking a question here on Meta about it.